# How to create a one to many relation between models in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've students and courses in my ruby models and controllers, so i want to connect this two things and show an user and the courses he have registered and click those courses to see what is inside that course. i'm new to ruby so i don't know much about has_many and i cant find something that can make what i want to work

i've use scaffold to create the models and controllers,
user only have a name, email and courses only have course_name

student:

```
 create_table :student do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
```

course:

```
create_table :course do |t|
  t.string :name

  t.timestamps
```

in the index of students i only list all of the students i have.
help please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you want to use a many-to-many association between `students` and `courses`. There are a number of ways to achieve this. I would go with the `has_many :though` option described [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association), in which you add an additional model called `StudentCourse`.

So in your scenario, you would:

1. generate this StudenCourse model with `rails generate model StudentCourse student:references model:references`
2. add the following to your `Student` model

```
    class Student
      ...
      has_many :student_courses
      has_many :courses, through: student_courses
      ...
    end
```

3. add the following to your `Course` model

```
    class Course
      ...
      has_many :student_courses
      has_many :students, through: student_courses
      ...
    end
```

4. run migrations with `rake db:migrate`
5. now you can start adding students to courses and vice versa. For example:

```
    Student.last.courses << Course.last
    Course.first.students << Student.first
```

and in your controllers, you can simply call `student.courses` to see courses that are associated with a given student, or `course.students` to view students taking a specific course.

notice how both `Course` and `Student` models will are now associated with each other using `has_many: ..., through: :student_courses`.

Another benefit of using this type of many-to-many association is flexibility. For instance, you might want to start recording whether students have dropped specific courses. You can do so by simply adding a `dropped_at` column to this new `student_courses` table.

#### EDIT

adding a few more detailed examples of how to use this new association:

as mentioned, you can append courses to students and vice versa via rails console. For instance, a student with id of 1 wants to enroll into a course with id of 2:

```
Student.find(1).courses << Course.find(2)
```

similarly, you can just add students to courses like so:

```
Course.find(2).students << Student.find(1)
```

under the hood, both of these associations would be creating a new instance of the `StudentCourse` class we added. So a third option of creating this association would be:

```
StudentCourse.create(student: Student.find(1), course: Course.find(2))
```

Comment: in point five you say i can start adding some courses, but where i can do that? in the console of ruby or somewhere else

Comment: you can do this in the rails console, or in controller actions, or service objects etc. I added a few more examples of how to append students to courses with ids

Answer (score 3):

What you most likely want here is actually a many to many assocation. Not one to many.

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :courses, through: :enrollments
end

class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :courses, through: :enrollments
end

class Enrollment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :course
end
```

This lets you use `courses` as a normalization table which contains the information about the course instead of duplicating it for each student.

`enrollments` works as a join table and lets you join any number of students to any number of courses. Its also where you would store information that describes the relation between student and course - like for example the students grade (marks).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the relations i.e. associations in your model classes.

You propably have two model classes in a folder named app/models by now (assuming scaffolding has created them):

- app/models/student.rb
- app/models/curso.rb

in app/models/student.rb you need to have something like this:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :curso

end
```

in app/models/curso.rb you need to have something like this:

```
class Curso < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :students

end
```

That's how associations are being created in rails.

Comment: Why the strange spelling?

Comment: That's the spelling/naming which was used in the question's original post. It must have been updated since I wrote my answer.